# Real-time iterating measurements frame by frame in Matlab

Tags: matlab, real-time, frame, imaging, sliding-window

I am using Matlab to perform real time imaging. I wish to iterate over the 60 measurements frame by frame. Each frame should contain 10 measurements. The incoming data is saved into a buffer and reconstructed when first 10 measurements (1-10) are received. Then the frame move forward to next 10 measurements (2-11) when the 11th repetition is received. These 10 measurements (2-11) are saved into the buffer and make average with the previous image (1-10). The sliding idea is in followings.

```
1st iteration: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10} 
2nd iteration: 1 {2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11} 
3rd iteration: 1 2 {3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12} 
Last iteration: 1 2 3 4 5...48 49 50 {51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60}
```

The main problem here would be how to iterate the measurements frame by frame in Matlab? Could iterator make this?

Comment: What do you mean "output the data".  The question is a bit unclear, can you expand your explanation?

Comment: Please edit your question with the code, dont put it in a comment. Also, take some time to rewrite the question. I have absolutely no idea of what you want to do, and you comment didnt help me much!